# jQuery .bind and .unbind with other click functions

Tags: jquery

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/4H94J/).

The `click` function `unbinds` correctly but when i click on the button `Edit 1` but it doesnt binds it back.

What have i been doing wrong ?
Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're not rebinding your click handler to any particular function (and it doesn't seem to say anywhere in the docs that it should be rebound to the previous handler if you call `bind` without a handler). So, you have to change your code like this:

```
var words = $("p:first").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span> <span class='la'>");
$("p:first").html("<span class='la'>" + text + "</span>");
function spanclick(){
    $(this).html('<input class="mm" value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
    $(this).unbind("click");
}
$("span.la").click(spanclick);
$("span.la").unbind("click");
$("#hmm").delegate(".mm", "blur", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<span>" + $(this).val() + "</span>");
    $(this).bind("click");
    $("#get").html($("p").text());
});
$("#ed1").click(function() {
    $("#get").html("Editing 1");
    console.log('aaa');
    $("span.la").bind("click", spanclick);
});
$("#ed2").click(function() {
    $("#get").html("Editing 2");
});
```

But that's not all. Apparently, something's wrong with your CSS too, because the `ed1`  div is not catching click events. It was fixed when I removed all of the CSS.